# Array decay, passing and recieving pointers to arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, computer-science

Please help me understand what happens here:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int *ar) {std::cout << sizeof(arr) << '\n' << arr[3];} // exceeding array bounds on purpose 

int main()
{
   int arr[2]{3, 5};
   foo(arr);

   return 0;
}
```

Is this an example of array decay?
And what exactly is *arr? Is it a pointer-to-int, or is it a pointer-to-array (of int)? In case of the latter, does it carry information about the address of a memory block holding the array? If not, how is it possible to use array notation inside a function that only recieves a pointer to its first element?

Then,

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int *ar) {std::cout << sizeof(arr) << '\n' << arr[1];}

int main()
{
   int arr[2][1]{{3}, {5}};
   foo(*arr);

   return 0;
}
```

What happens in case of a 2D array? What does *arr represent here when passed? Is it the pointer to the first element of the right array? What does it represent when taken as an argument by a function?

*edit: changed array name in foo*

Comment: `int *arr` is a pointer to a single `int`. The question would be more clear if you would give different names to `arr` in `main` and `arr` in `foo`

Comment: *Is it a pointer-to-int,* -- `void foo(int *arr)` --> It should be clear what it is, as it says right there what it is.  It can't be anything else.

Comment: Why put all the effort in understanding pointer decay when you can use std::array and/or std::vector. In my experience using "C" style arrays only leads to bugs

Comment: `arr[3]` is syntactic sugar for `*(arr + 3)`.  You could even do `3[arr]` for fun, but don't do that in real code.

Comment: Example using std::array : https://onlinegdb.com/NB6b7ow_y1.  In current C++ if you run into a pointer check if you can solve it in another way e.g. using one of the stl containers.

Comment: In the second, `*arr` is equivalent to `arr[0]`, which is an array with one element. That array behaves exactly like all other arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is an example of an array decaying into a pointer.

`int* arr` is a pointer to the first element of the array.  The address is guaranteed to be the same as the address of the array, but the type is different.

In `foo(*arr)`, you are dereferencing a `int[2][1]`, an array of 2 elements where each element is an array of 1 element.  This gives you a `int(&)[1]` - a reference to an array of one elements.  This then decays to a pointer to the first element of the 1 element array.

Now, why does `int*arr; arr[2]` work?  Well, `ptr[n]` in C and C++ is *defined* to mean `*(ptr+n)`.  So much so that `n[ptr]` works (!).  (do NOT do `n[ptr]` ever)

Array indexing on normal arrays even works this way.  `int arr[3]; arr[2]` is actually doing a decay-of-array-to-pointer, then doing `+2` on that pointer, then dereferencing.

C was designed as a slightly portable assembly language.  And in assembly, array indexing is adding (with some multiplication) then a load instruction.

`pointer + int` in this model converts both to ints, then scales the int by the size of the pointed to thing, adds them up, then converts back to pointers and does a load.

The C++ and C standards doesn't actually *say* this is what is going on, because they both talk about things more abstractly to permit a variety of implementations to exist.  But that is the model they are based off of.